# Change tag name <Emp> to <Employee> while marshaling in jibx?

Tags: jibx, maven-jibx

I have a scenario where the XML may be like `<emp><name></name></emp>` etc i want to 
change the tags to `<employee>` while marshaling is this possible ??? Please help